# boolean not evaluating to true although conditions are met

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So I have a static variable called isSuccessful all the variable is supposed to do is, be true if someone was able to login successfully or be false if they couldn't. I have it set to false by default. The php script I wrote sends the message "loginsuccess" and stores it in the onProgressUpdate parameters. I debugged to see if that's what was being stored in the parameters, and the compile says it is. well then I can't figure out why isSuccessful isn't being switched to true. I set it to do that. once that happens, I have the login activity call the homeScreen activity.
LoginTask:

```
public class LogInTask extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {
    public Scanner reader;
    Formatter writer;
    Context mcontext;

    //if Login was successful
    public static boolean isSuccessful;

    LogInTask(Context context)
    {
        mcontext = context;

    }

    URL url;
    URLConnection con;
    String output = "";


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        isSuccessful=false;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.75:1234/login.php");
            con = url.openConnection();
            //allows to send information
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            //allows to receive information
            con.setDoInput(true);
            writer = new Formatter(con.getOutputStream());
            //Sends login information to SQL table
            writer.format("user_name="+params[0]+"&password="+params[1]);
            writer.close();

            //Reads input
            reader = new Scanner(con.getInputStream());
            while(reader.hasNext())
            {

                output+= reader.next();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(output);

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        Toast.makeText(mcontext, values[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(values[0]=="loginsuccess")
            isSuccessful = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

LogInActivity:

```
public class LogInActivity extends Activity {
    private Typeface fontRobo;
    private TextView logoText;
    private EditText userName;
    private EditText passWord;

    private TextView dontHave;
    private TextView signUp;

    private Button logIn;
    Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

        //Logo
        logoText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Logo);
        fontRobo = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/ROBO.ttf");
        logoText.setText("ArtSpace");
        logoText.setTypeface(fontRobo);

        //Don't have an account?
        dontHave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Donthave);
        dontHave.setTypeface(fontRobo);

        //Sign Up
        signUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUP);
        signUp.setTypeface(fontRobo);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);

        logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn);

    }
    //Log in button event
    public void logInClick(View view)
    {
        final LogInTask task = new LogInTask(LogInActivity.this);
        task.execute(userName.getText().toString(), passWord.getText().toString());
        if(LogInTask.isSuccessful)
            startActivity(i);

    }
```

php:

```
<?php
    require "conn.php";
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['password'];
    $mysql_qry = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE UserName LIKE '$user_name' AND Password LIKE '$user_pass';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == true)
    {
        echo "login  success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "login not success";

    }
?>
```

Comment: there is no php here

Comment: @nogad added php

Comment: Your sql query is 1) open for sql injections, 2) using LIKE instead of exact comparisons, 3) letting the database do string comparisons, probably case-insensitive, 4) using passwords stored in clear-text.

Comment: @simon Svensson yeah I need to fix all that. Its my first time doing this so I'm still learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`task.execute()` is AsyncTask aka it takes time to execute. But you are checking right after you call it. You need to make the check for isSuccessful  in `onPostExecute()` block.
Something like this:

```
  final LogInTask task = new LogInTask(LogInActivity.this){
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if(LogInTask.isSuccessful)
        startActivity(i);
    }};
    task.execute(userName.getText().toString(), passWord.getText().toString());
```

PS: Something else, do not compare Strings with `==` use `.equals()`

```
if(values[0].equals("loginsuccess"))
```

Comment: tried it, still no luck. debugged it again and s is equal to "loginsuccess" but still for some reason or the other isSuccessful is still remaining false.

Comment: yeah it was a silly mistake by me. your solution worked. thanks.

Comment: By the way what is it called when you type a method like tgat? You put the method inside the variable. What's that called?

Comment: Its Anonymous Classes - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html